# How to group Stata coefplot (recast as bar) bars together by dependent variable?

Tags: regression, grouping, visualization, stata

I am trying to make a plot in Stata that examines the probit regression for 7 dependent variables (each observation having a value of 0 or 1) based on a single categorical variable.

My code is quite simple, it is:

estimates clear
foreach var in $midlevels {
probit `var' i.hasws margins, over(hasws) post estimates store` var'
}

coefplot $midlevels, recast(bar) vertical barwidth(0.1) yscale(range(0 1)) ci(95) scheme(s1) ///

graph export "{file address}.png", replace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALzlH.png)

When I do this, I get the attached image as an output. Technically readable, but a bad visualization...

I'd like to get it such that instead of the bars being color coded to represent the dependent variable, they are grouped together by dependent variable (i.e. b8bmid bars are the first two, b9bmid bars are the 3rd and 4th, and so on). Then, I'd like those pairs of bars to be color coded to represent whether they are visualizing observations that have a website or not.

Have been unable to solve this with much effort thus far. Does anyone have a suggestion?

-Tried recasting as a different type of plot.

-Tried separating each variable in the coefplot call with ||, which "worked," but it made 7 different plots and just saved them together, and I didn't like that.

-Tried removing different pieces of the code.